# Is possible to overwrite a function in the htmlbuilder?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm working on the [pydata-sphinx-theme](https://github.com/pydata/pydata-sphinx-theme). What we currently (v0.12) do is overwritting the html builder to add specific behaviours to the `visit_table`, and `starttag` to make the created component compatible with bootstrap (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pydata-sphinx-theme/blob/main/src/pydata_sphinx_theme/bootstrap_html_translator.py)).

The problem of this method is that some building website has their own HtmlBuilder that we then need to overwrite as well (e.g. RTD):

```py
app.set_translator("html", BootstrapHTML5Translator)
# Read the Docs uses ``readthedocs`` as the name of the build, and also
# uses a special "dirhtml" builder so we need to replace these both with
# our custom HTML builder
app.set_translator("readthedocs", BootstrapHTML5Translator, override=True)
app.set_translator("readthedocsdirhtml", BootstrapHTML5Translator, override=True)
```

This poses some compatibility issues and as there are very few things we would prefer not to override the full builder (https://github.com/pydata/pydata-sphinx-theme/issues/94) but only the 2 visiting functions.

Is there a way to do such a thing in Sphinx?

Comment: cant you just subclass it(BootstrapHTML5Translator or the other HTMLbuilder) and override the two functions?

Comment: this is exactly what we are doing now, the issue is that any website with a custom translator needs to be known in advance to be subclassed (using `app.set_translator`).